# How to save response and use in Microsoft Bot Builder in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, botframework

How can I achieve this? So I did this:

```
.matches('Football position', (session, results) => {
    session.send("So you are looking for a \%s\ position. ", session.message.text);


 function (session, args, next) {
      builder.Prompts.confirm(session, "Did that solve your problem buddy !");
 },
 function (session, args) {
      if (args.response) {
         session.send("good by");
      else {
         session.send("Please try again");
 }


})
```

So, first: a confirmation regarding the previous answer the person gave. 
Then: a dialog where the user can put in NO or YES. Based on the answer, I want to go a different way and show a different message, but it does not work at all.

Could someone help, please?

Comment: I wonder about this too... any help?

Comment: Can you add the rest of your code for the dialog and be a little more specific on what you mean by "go a different way"? Do you mean to another dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is a mistake in your code snippet, the second parameter of function [`matches()`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/core/lib/botbuilder.d.ts#L3316) should be a `tring|IDialogWaterfallStep[]|IDialogWaterfallStep`. You need to modifty your code snippet as:

```
matches('Football position',[(session,args)=>{},(session,args)=>{}...])
```

Second, `send()` will not keep the state in the waterfall steps, which means, your user never will step into the following steps via your code snippet. If you attempt to recieve user's input, you can use [`IPrompts`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/core/lib/botbuilder.d.ts#L3459).

> Then: a dialog where the user can put in NO or YES

You can leverage choice to achieve this:

```
bot.dialog('/', [
    (session) => {
        var msg = new builder.Message(session)
            .text("Did that solve your problem buddy !")
            .suggestedActions(
                builder.SuggestedActions.create(
                    session, [
                        builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "Yes", "Yes"),
                        builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "No", "No")
                    ]
                )
            );
        builder.Prompts.choice(session, msg, ["Yes", "No"]);
    },
    (session, args, next) => {
        if (args.response.entity == "Yes") {
            session.send("You selected Yes")
        } else {
            session.send("You selected No")
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of a dialog after receiving user input?

Comment: Magnificent. Thank you very much!